# Way to remove newline (^M) from variables only, not from file

Tags: bash, text-processing, newlines

I am loading a file into variables, the problem is that the file is formatted in Windows, I believe, so I get a `^M` instead of a newline.

How do I modify it when the value is in the variable? I am aware that I can modify the source in VI (I use OS X, by the way), but I can't modify the original file, only read it, so I have to remove the `^M` from the variable.

From my understanding, `\n` is not the same as `^M`, so `tr` command won't work.

EDIT

It seems the question is not clear; so this is the clarification.

I do parse the file line by line; each line has a 2 values, separated by tab and at the end of each line, there is a ^M, it does look like this:

```
value1    value2^M
value3    value4^M
value5    value6^M
value7    value8^M
```

My workflow is pretty straightforward and simple: the txt file contain what you see above, the loop separate fields and for each line get the values; when I print the second value it has the ^M, which I would like to remove

```
while IFS=$'\t' read -r -a line
do
    Type1="${line[0]}"
    Type2="${line[1]}"
done < $TXTFILE
```

Which means taht when I print Type1 it is fine, but Type2 variable contain the ^M.
I did use `tr` and it didn't work, I did use `sed` to remove the last character of the variable, and it didn't work. Hope this clarify my question. Thanks

Comment: how are you reading the file into variable? might be possible to remove it during that... for ex: use `sed 's|\r||' file` instead of `file`

Comment: I was going to answer with `tr` but the question is way to broad.  We don't know what the input or output are, nor what the script looks like.

Comment: I did add more info to the question; I load the file with standard loop in bash, changing IFS to tab, so I can divide the line in 2 parts and get the 2 variables. I did try TR but it didn't work, same for sed; which is why I did go ahead and posted the question here. Thanks

Comment: I find strange that you accept an unnecessarily complex solution. Did you try mine?

Comment: Also see [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/135943)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`^M` is a carriage return (CR), which can be specified as `\r` for `tr` or within `$'…'`. `\n` specifies a line feed (LF), which is `^J`. A Unix line ending is LF, and a Windows line separator is the two-character sequence CR-LF, so Windows text files viewed under a Unix system such as Linux or macOS look like they have `^M` at the end of each line except on the last line which is missing its final newline.

You can remove carriage returns from a file with `tr` with

```
tr -d '\r' <somefile.txt >somefile.txt.new && mv somefile.txt.new somefile.txt
```

or more simply with `dos2unix`.

To avoid modifying the files, you can check each line when you read it and strip CR at the end of a line. For example, if you're using `read` to parse tab-separated values, then strip CR at the end of the last field. The parameter expansion `${VAR%$'\r'}` yields the value of `VAR` minus a trailing CR, and yields the value of `VAR` if it doesn't end with CR.

```
while IFS=$'\t' read -r -a line
do
    line[$((${#line[@]}-1))]="${line[$((${#line[@]}-1))]%$'\r'}"
    Type1="${line[0]}"
    Type2="${line[1]}"
done < "$TXTFILE"
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that /r is in fact the same as ^M; the solution works

Comment: Note that OS/X comes with a very old version of `bash`, so I don't expect it would support `line[-1]` for which you need bash-4.3 or above. It comes with `zsh` that supports it (and has for decades), but note that in `zsh`, the first element is `$line[1]`, not `$line[0]` (unless in ksh emulation). With older `bash`, you can always use `line[${#line[@]}-1]`

Comment: +1 for the background explanation, but I think [jiliagre's solution](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/326157/135943) is much better, and **much** simpler.

Answer (score 8):

Here is the simplest way to fix your script, simply add "carriage return" as a internal field separator for the read command:

```
while IFS=$'\t\r' read -r -a line
do
  Type1="${line[0]}"
  Type2="${line[1]}"
done < $TXTFILE
```

Comment: @jiliagre, yes, you're right, it's taken as a delimiter there. That would be different in `zsh` where `$IFS` is taken as a separator.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thanks, you are too obsessed with `zsh` ;-)

Answer (score 7):

Use (for short strings):

```
${var//$'\015'}
```

Example:

```
$ var=$'This is a test of a CR (\r) character'
$ echo "${var//$'\r'}"
This is a test of a CR () character
```

For longer strings you may need sed or awk.

Answer (score 0):

A more generally useful way to convert the content of "DOS" files, which have no other content marker than having CR+LF line endings (in contrast to Linux' LF only).

For Ubuntu, first and once only, do

```
sudo apt install dos2unix
```

the use as indicated below, here with `od` used to verify the output

```
$ dos2unix < $TXTFILE | od -t x1z -w17 
0000000 76 61 6c 75 65 31 20 20 20 20 76 61 6c 75 65 32 0a  >value1    value2.<
0000021 76 61 6c 75 65 33 20 20 20 20 76 61 6c 75 65 34 0a  >value3    value4.<
0000042 76 61 6c 75 65 35 20 20 20 20 76 61 6c 75 65 36 0a  >value5    value6.<
0000063 76 61 6c 75 65 37 20 20 20 20 76 61 6c 75 65 38 0a  >value7    value8.<
0000104

$ cat $TXTFILE | od -t x1z -w18
0000000 76 61 6c 75 65 31 20 20 20 20 76 61 6c 75 65 32 0d 0a  >value1    value2..<
0000022 76 61 6c 75 65 33 20 20 20 20 76 61 6c 75 65 34 0d 0a  >value3    value4..<
0000044 76 61 6c 75 65 35 20 20 20 20 76 61 6c 75 65 36 0d 0a  >value5    value6..<
0000066 76 61 6c 75 65 37 20 20 20 20 76 61 6c 75 65 38 0d 0a  >value7    value8..<
0000110
```

This will translate not only the line endings but also other special characters, depending on the parameters to `dos2unix` or its counterpart `unix2dos` (which gets installed at the same time).

Comment: isn't dos2unix there by default?

Comment: I did clearly specified that I know how to do it via file modification; plus I am not using linux but OSX, so to install dos2unix I have to use brew

Comment: `dos2unix` isn't FIXATED to using FILE-modification, it is "a filter" and can be used in pipes; just like `tr`. It should also be preferred over `tr` as it handles charsets on a higher level, not only single byte codes.

Comment: @Lưu Vĩnh Phúc, I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and have a quite fresh install, and I had to install it.